# Is there something radically wrong with this XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have only an elementary understanding of XML Schema. This is basically my first interaction with them in any serious way and I'm having some issues. I've read up on XSDs on google and everything looks on the up and up with this file.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="credits">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="property" maxOccurs="16" minOccurs="13" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="property" type="xs:string">    
    <xs:complexType>        
        <xs:sequence>            
            <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="name" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="item" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="example1"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example2"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example3"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example4"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example5"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example6"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example7"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example8"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example9"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example10"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example11"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example12"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example13"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example14"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example15"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="example16"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>

</xs:schema>
```

Here's how I'm loading it:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance( XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI );
Schema schemaXSD = schemaFactory.newSchema( new File ( "test.xsd" ) );
```

I'm getting an exception like the following:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   src-element.3: Element 'property' has
>   both a 'type' attribute and a
>   'anonymous type' child. Only one of
>   these is allowed for an element.

Thanks for the help SO! Any general advice on reading/using schemas created by others is also appreciated! :D

Comment: There are a number of IDEs that can spot this kind of error at edition time (i.e. before you submit the XSD to your own code).  [eclipse J2E](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1) for instance will show little red markers in the right margin with the same error messages you cited)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit is your problem code:

```
<xs:element name="property" type="xs:string">    
    <xs:complexType>        
        <xs:sequence>            
            <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="name" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>
```

either remove the type on the outer element (`type="xs:string"`), or remove the anonymous inner complexType element (`<xs:complexType> ... </xs:complexType>`)

Comment: This will probably come up in the next bit of code, too. <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string">
      <xs:simpleType>. You've got two type declarations, and the system won't know which one to use.

Comment: then how will you tell that the element has an attribute without the use of completype?

Answer (score 6):

> Element 'property' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child

In other words, you say `type="xs:string"` and this prescribes nodes like `<property>foo</property>`. But also you put a ComplexType `item` inside the `property`, and this prescribes nodes like `<property><item>...</item></property>`. This is the contradiction which the parser considers an error.

If you want to store a number of `item`s in each `property` *and* one separate string per `property`, store this string as separate node, either a child with a tag, or an attribute of `property`. E.g. `<property mystring="foo"><item>...</item></property>`

Comment: then how will you tell that the element has an attribute without the use of completype? I thought that an attribute has element has to be come inside the complexType.